# NSInvalidArgumentException when working with NSArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

Im developing an iPhone application for iOS 5 and Im stucked in a array problem. I have one custom class that I've made that I call Persons. Persons consists of two arrays. One for the boys and one for the girls. First I want to fill the Persons object using an method from another class, and Im pretty sure that this works like it should. But when I'm going to split up the arrays into single arrays from the Persons object in the code it doesn't work. It feels like the Persons object, or its arrays is stucked in some way. Please help. This code are throwing me an error that looks like: `2012-07-24 09:29:03.073 PersonApp[4375:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary Boys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6ac0fe0'`

**Persons.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Persons : NSObject {
    NSArray *Boys;
    NSArray *Girls;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *Boys;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *Girls;

@end
```

**PersonsViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Persons.h"

@interface PersonsViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) Persons *persons;

@end
```

**PersonsViewController.m**

```
#import "PersonsViewController.h"

NSArray *boys;
NSArray *girls;
...................
@synthesize persons;     
...................
Communication *comm = [[Communication alloc] init];    
self.persons = [comm getPersons];
boys = [self.persons Boys];
girls = [self.persons Girls];
```

Answer (score 1):

what is [comm getPersons] returning ? I think it is not "Persons" object. Try this code.

```
if ([[comm getPersons] isKindOfClass:[Persons class]])
{
   NSLog(@"Not returning Persons object. So this is the error!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

........ I could be wrong here,

but have you tried something like

```
NSArray *boys = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray[[comm getPersons]boys]autorelease];
```

I'm sorry it's been a few weeks since I've last had Xcode open, so apologies for any code mistakes,

Are you initalizing/allocating memory to the NSArray, do something like

```
NSLog(@"count %d",[[[comm getPersons]boys]count]);
```

That should at least show you that the boys array exists, (assuming its been created)...

NSLog is your best friend, i would also recommend learning how to use the debugger.